# Вставка в линейный список после определенного элемента

Tags: c, структуры, односвязный-список

```
struct Node {
    int Data;
    Node* next;
};
```

Так выглядит структура

Таким образом сделал добавление и этим вызовом вставлял

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        a = add(a, i);

Node* add(Node *head, int Value)
{
    Node *New = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    New->Data = Value;
    New->next = head;
    return New;
}
```

Но теперь пытаюсь вставить следующим элементом от del новый , но так, чтобы он раздвинул линейный список и встал между вторым и первым.И что-то пошло не так.
Вот так нахожу нужный элемент:

```
Node* Find(Node *head, int Value)
{
    while (head)
    {
        if (head->Data == Value)
            return head;
        head = head->next;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

А сам вывоз выглядит вот так : **Node *del = Find(a, 2);**

```
Node* add1(Node* head,Node* del)
{
    Node *New = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    New->Data = 777;
    del->next = New;
    New->next = del->next->next;
    return head;
}
```

Пытаюсь вставить между вторым и первым число 777.Проблема в последней функции , не пойму как исправить

Comment: После того, как вы сделали `del->next = New;`, выражение `del->next->next` - это то же самое, что и `New->next`. То есть последующее `New->next = del->next->next;` - это просто бессмысленное `New->next = New->next;`. Присваивание мусора самому себе.

Comment: Обычно в листалке вводят рекурсию, для более быстрового поиска, что то типа `Node* prev;` и вставлять удобнее (понятнее) и искать можно сразу в 2 стороны. При этом prev = структура до, next = после. Для предыдущей структуры next = вставляемая, для следующей prev = вставляемая структура.

Comment: В вашем же коде надо: `New->next = del; return New;` вроде так, попробовать сейчас не нечем :) правда неясно в каком виде туда head попадает, в каком месте..

Comment: Хотел написать пример, но поленился, гугл знает все о [листалке](http://www.learn-c.org/en/Linked_lists) и [двойная листалке 1](https://gist.github.com/mycodeschool/7429492) и [двойная листалке 2](https://gist.github.com/ArnonEilat/4471119) :)

Comment: @AnT,но я же просто пытаюсь установить связь между элементами имеющимися и вставляемым , как иначе это провернуть?

Comment: @Elvin Прекрасно. Устанавливать связь нужно. Только делать это надо правильно - в правильном порядке. Вы слишком рано перетираете оригинальное значение `New->next`.

Answer (score 0):

Дошло

```
Node* add1(Node* head,Node* del)
{
    Node *New = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    New->Data = 777;
    New->next = del->next;
    del->next = New;

    return head;
}
```